# odoo clicking button "Produce"

Tags: odoo

I am working on the android application that connects to Odoo(OpenErp 8).In my application I want to have a button and when I click the button I want the "produce" button in Manufacturing module in Odoo to be clicked as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hello i found a solution for that 
i have made a odoo client connector using json RPC.
 https://github.com/GauravSahu/odoo-client-JSON-RPC
in odoo.js you can put your function and using following string you can call

```
client_req = {
"opts" : {
    "login" : "admin",
        "password" : "123",
        "db" : "test",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": "8069"
},
"moduleDetail" : {
    "model" : "hr.employee",
    "method" : "create",
    "args" : {
        "name" : "Gaurav"
    },
    "filter" : "",
    "fields" : "",
    "domain" : "",
    "offset" : "",
    "limit" : "",
    "sort" : "",
    "resource_id":""
}
```

}

Here create function called...

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the action_produce method from [mrp](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/mrp/mrp.py#L970). Just called it in same way as you call the other objects like create, search etc with the required params.

```
def action_produce(self, cr, uid, production_id, production_qty, production_mode, wiz=False, context=None):
...
```

It might also necessary to trigger the signal to follow the workflow properly otherwise I think your workflow will be broken. Here is how you can call the work for produce.

```
self.signal_workflow(cr, uid, [production_id], 'button_produce')
```

Answer (score 0):

As in Odoo buttons are either action or object.
So you can make RPC call to call that method which is call through the "Produce" button.

Answer (score 0):

The `Produce` button opens a wizard and let you choose the mode, quantity and the products to consume then you need to confirm your choice by clicking on `confirm` button, So you have to show a similar wizard to the user and use an `AsynchTask` class to call `confirm` button in background.

- Add `mrp_product_produce` and `mrp_product_produce_line` to your models.
- Add an activity to show the values like on odoo server.
- The click on `confim` button should call `do_produce` present in `mrp.product.produce` like they did at [SalesDetail](https://github.com/Odoo-mobile/crm/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/odoo/addons/sale/SalesDetail.java#L225).